# VB.Net - How to Change attributes of Folder included sub folder & files

Tags: vb.net, attributes, subdirectory

How to change or remove attribute of selected folder including all sub folders & files.

I used the following code :

```
System.IO.SetAttribute(FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath,IO.FileAttribute.Hidden)
```

But it changes only selected folder attributes not sub folders & files

Comment: You would need to loop all sub directories off the directory from what the user picked, a recursive function... Right now, you are immediately just changing it for the selected directory. Before setting the attributes make a loop retrieving each directory and their files and then set that attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over subfolder recursively. I think that OS do that recursively too!!

```
Private Function getAllFolders(ByVal directory As String) As List(of String)
        'Create object
        Dim fi As New IO.DirectoryInfo(directory)
        'Change main folder attribute
        System.IO.SetAttribute(directory,IO.FileAttribute.Hidden )
        'List to store paths
        Dim Folders As New List(Of String)
        'Loop through subfolders
        For Each subfolder As IO.DirectoryInfo In fi.GetDirectories()
            'Add this folders name

           Folders.Add(subfolder.FullName)

            'Recall function with each subdirectory
            For Each s As String In getAllFolders(subfolder.FullName)
                Folders.Add(s)
                'Change subfolders attribute
                System.IO.SetAttribute(s,IO.FileAttribute.Hidden )
            Next

        Next


        Return Folders

 End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

All subfolders and files can be enumerated like this:

```
If FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then

    Dim di = New IO.DirectoryInfo(FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath)
    di.Attributes = di.Attributes Or FileAttributes.Hidden

    For Each i In di.EnumerateFileSystemInfos("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        i.Attributes = i.Attributes Or FileAttributes.Hidden
    Next
End If
```

---

Another way can be with [attrib.exe](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754186):

```
Dim cmd = "attrib +H """ & FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath.TrimEnd("\"c)

Shell("cmd /c " & cmd & """ & " & cmd & "\*"" /S /D", AppWinStyle.Hide)
```

I expect it to be faster than enumerating all file entries and getting and setting the attributes of each one separately, but another advantage of this method is that by default the shell function does not wait for the command to complete and your program can continue without waiting.